# Separate Configuration File for Same Job executed under separate scenarios

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch with Spring boot.

I have two jobs which I execute using the below:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimeWorkedJobLauncher.class);

private final Job job;
//private final Job jobDS;

private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;


@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

@Autowired
TimeWorkedJobLauncher(@Qualifier("timeworkedJob") Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    System.out.println("Inside TimeWorkedJobLauncher");
    this.job = job;
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    //this.jobDS = jobDS;
}


@Async
@Scheduled(cron = "${reports.timeWorked.job.cron}")
public void execute() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException,
        JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    LOGGER.info("Starting TimeWorked job");
    JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    builder.addDate("date", new Date());
    builder.addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis());
    builder.addString(LoaderConstants.JOB_PARAMETER, resourceLoader.getTimeWorkedFileLoc());

    jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());


    LOGGER.info("Stopping TimeWorked job");
}


    @Async
    @Scheduled(cron = "${reports.timeWorked.job.cronds}")
    public void executeDSJob() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException,
            JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {

        JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        builder.addDate("date", new Date());
        builder.addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.addString(LoaderConstants.JOB_PARAMETER, resourceLoader.getTimeWorkedFileLocForDS());
        jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());


        LOGGER.info("Stopping TimeWorked job for DS");
    }
```

The only difference is that when I run the executeDSJob() I need the job to execute different beforeStep() and afterStep() methods as the ones executed when I run the job using  execute().

I have two configuration classes configured, the only difference being that one class returns

```
@Bean
    public StepExecutionListener timeworkedCountProcessor() {
        return new TimeWorkedProcessorDS();
    }
```

and the other returns

```
@Bean
    public StepExecutionListener timeworkedCountProcessor() {
        return new TimeWorkedProcessor();
    }
```

But when I run the execute() method the TimeWorkedProcessorDS() is used and the afterStep() and beforeStep() of this class are being used.

How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like you have the same bean named `timeworkedCountProcessor` declared twice (in two different config classes that are both loaded). Hence, one is overriding the other. Have you tried to give them different names? If this does not work, please share your job configuration and show which application contexts are loaded in the class where `execute` and `executeDSJob` are defined.

Comment: Yes. That was the mistake. It worked when i gave them different names.Thank you.